# Can our AWS direct connect be accessed by others?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We're turning up an AWS direct connect circuit soon for some internal transfers, mainly for backups between our instances in EC2 and some colo'd resources near AWS. The details of the data and our backup procedures aren't really that important for this question. Some of our other data is public and we would like to offer it to other AWS users. mainly people that we've worked with in the past.

It seems like the most efficient way to do this would be over the direct connect link. Would we be able to offer this data over the direct connect circuit to other AWS users, or is transfer limited only to the instances on our account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billing for Direct Connect and the physical interface for the circuit can only be associated with one AWS account, however you can [associate virtual interfaces with different accounts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/pricing.html)

Comment: I understand the billing, but would the resources that we connect up through direct connect, namely our backup/fileservers, would our partners be able to access those files/resources over the direct connect link? Or is that access restricted only to us, transfer between the direct connected servers and our EC2 instances?

Comment: Direct Connect establishes a private connection between your AWS resources on your account, and the port on the other end (e.g. switch port at peering point you own, or port provided by a Direct Connect partner).  If you wanted someone off your network to connect to your AWS resources over the Direct Connect connection, they would have to make the connection via your network. You would be responsible for the mechanisms to make that possible (e.g. firewall ingress policy, network configuration etc).